# Compare value column to value Dax string not working, How may I compare one Dax with searching a singular value with another table?

Tags: powerbi, dax

If I compare columns with one Dax with string anything happens

[image]

[image]

But if I use the string directly the filter happens

[image]

The objective is to get the country excluded in the previous Dax

[image]

[image]

Code about LadingCode and Shipment Selected 2.0

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share [LoadingCode] measure.

Comment: Hi friend, I did add the measures!

Answer (score 0):

OK. Personally , I think that your shipment selected 2.0 measure is returning the last condition 'No[t] shipment selected', failing all others:

Please ensure that at least one of them returns a value.

[image: CDFGG]